How to interpret cross tabulation with the hypothesis so that it is not confusing?
(This is not a homework looking for answers but rather like a discussion on the methodology)
The hypothesis is: older people are less likely to speak a foreign language.

chi square test result is significant, so the two variable has significant relationship (null hypothesis of independence is rejected)
Cramer's V shows medium strength of relationship

The cross tab results are like this:

There could be two interpretations:
Interpretation 1 - The hypothesis is accepted because among those who say yes, there is a tendency of higher amount of younger population : 37.3% are under age 30, 18.7% are between 30-39, 17.5% are between 40-49, 11.6% are between 50-59, and only 15% are above 60.
Interpretation 2 - The hypothesis is accepted because among different age groups, there is a tendency of higher amount of younger population say yes: 70,8% are under age 30, 39,6% are between 30-39, 42,1% are between 40-49, 27,5% are between 50-59 and 19,3% are above 60.
My questions are:

Could anyone help justify from theory/convention that why in Interpretation 1 reading the percentages (37.3%, 18.7%, 17.5%, 11.6%,15.0%) is not appropriate for this hypothesis testing (It is showing the same trend as the column percentages.)
Can I justify like this: the row percentages are not meaningful here because since we didn't sample those who say yes in the population but we sample the age groups.

Is there any rule of thumb of which percentages should one look? For example: if you make X as an independent variable, in the SPSS crosstab you should always look at the percentages "%within X cohorts"

I found it confusing and not reliable to use crosstab results in testing such hypothesis, why is this method useful at all?



The phrases following "because" are not explanations: they merely recite some percentages.  Can you state what it is about those percentages that might support either conclusion?  If you're unsure, find a meaningful way to plot the data and examine the plot.

Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its
wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you
is grounds for closing.

The claim is that “older people are less likely to speak a foreign language” (from what I understand the question to be).  This can be translated into the NHST (null hypothesis statistical testing) framework with these hypotheses:
$$\begin{align}H_o &:  \pi_1 \le \pi_2 \\
H_a &: \pi_1 > \pi_2\end{align}$$
where $\pi_1$ is the proportion of the “younger” population speaking a foreign language and $\pi_2$ is the proportion of the “older” population speaking a foreign language.  As such, these are both conditional probabilities where the condition is the age status.  Thus, you would need to use the (conditional) proportions from the % within age cohorts.
For demonstration purposes only, I will use the lowest and oldest age groups.  To prove your claim, you would run the test with the 70.8% from the youngest group speaking a language compared to the 19.3% from the oldest group speaking a language.
Of course, the analysis gets a little more complicated if you wish to account for all categories in your analysis, but that is manageable.
Happy to clarify more if needed.

Thanks! My main confusion is in what defines reading the row percentage and what defines reading the column percentage. Does your answer mean that we should find the condition variable and then read the percentages of the condition variable in the table to justify the hypothesis?
However, I still do not understand why interpretation 1 is not appropriate. The tendency in interpretation 1 is similar as the one in interpretation 2. But what is the risk/problem of using  interpretation 1? Is there other counter example to help understanding why we shall not use interpretation 1?

Interpretation is %s conditioned on the row in which the frequencies are located. Interpretation is %s conditioned on the column in which the frequencies are located. If your query is about comparing the groups as they appear in the different columns, then the 2nd interpretation is indeed the correct (conditional) frequencies/proportions on which to focus.

Also, the statement of interpretation #2 would be better stated as:  among the different age groups, the %s saying yes within those groups are...[fill in the %s listed there here]...AND, I would suggest you can improve this question on this system by making an edit to fix that 2nd interpretation you had originally.

@GreggH OP's post sounds like the question comes from a textbook, so it's possible that the second interpretation is deliberately phrased like that, and that the point is that OP can't fix it.

The first problem is that you seem fixated on using proportions (i.e. percentages). But if these came from a total population of, say, 15, or ~1,500 (your case), the interpretation would be very different (not significant in the first case, very likely significant in the 2nd). So look at the counts, and counts only.
The 2nd issue is that your "interpretations" only look at observed counts/proportions. So if e.g. the 2nd age group (30-39) had 105 counts, or 39.6%, and the 3rd group (40-49) had 98 counts, or 42.1%, would you say that you accept the hypothesis that the 3rd group is more likely to speak a foreign language than the 2nd (after all, 42.1% > 39.6%)? Hopefully not; that difference is small, it may be due to just "dumb luck" (i.e. random sampling variability). So you need to run a statistical test, to see if there is a "statistically significant" difference between the age groups.
The last issue is that the table, as presented, and while it contains all the needed information, is not immediately amenable to a statistical test (and even contains rows, such as "% within Can you read or speak a foreign language?" which are not relevant, distracting and possibly confusing.
You have 5 age categories; lay them out as the headings of 5 columns. You have a dichotomous outcome (Speak a foreign language? yes/no). Lay it out as the headings of 2 rows. You now have a 5x2 matrix. In each cell, enter the respective counts (e.g. for the first age group, 209 for Yes, 86 for No). You now created a 5x2 contingency matrix (see wiki for more details).
Several tests can be run on it; for example Fisher-exact or Chi-square ($\chi^2)$; see wiki here, or here. Now, all these tests will tell you is whether all age groups are similar in their ability to speak a foreign language, or not. If you get a significant result, all you know is that yes, there are significant differences in the proportions.
Now you can create new contingency matrices, but this time only 2x2, to compare pairs of age groups (there will be 10 of these), using the same tests. Each test will tell you if there is a statistically significant difference between the 2 groups in question, or not.
Now, you will be performing 11 tests (1 5x2, 10 2x2); your chance of a false positive result (alpha, or Type I error) have increased significantly (e.g. if you used a .05 significance (tradition), they went from 5% to ~43%). So you should use a multiple comparison correction (MCC); e.g. Bonferonni, or Sidak, Sidak being a -little bit- less conservative.
Now, if all you really care about is comparing the younger group, to the older group, and have no interest in any other comparison, you simply run a single 2x2 contingency matrix, with no MCC. Fwiw, you should find that last one "very" significant...
